# Validate Git Config File Values

Tags: git, git-config

For defined git config variables with a finite set of valid values, is there a way to validate the values in the config file are valid?

For example if I enter an **invalid** value:

```
git config --global push.default simp
```

vs a **valid** value

```
git config --global push.default simple
```

Is there a way to detect this other than the behavior not working the way you intended?

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this is [both no and yes](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/207329-go-not-to-the-elves-for-counsel-for-they-will).

Given any *particular* name or set of names, there may be some limited set of correct value options.  That set may depend on your *Git version* as well.  For instance, `pull.rebase` (new in Git 1.7.9) can be set to:

- `false`: `git pull` will use `git merge` as its second command
- `true`: `git pull` will use `git rebase` as its second command
- `preserve`, since Git (1.8.5): `git pull` will use `git rebase -p` as its second command
- `interactive`, since Git 2.8: `git pull` will use `git rebase -i` as its second command
- `merges`, since Git 2.18: `git pull` will use `git rebase -r` as its second command

So the set of valid values for Git 2.18 or later is not the same as the set of valid values for Git 2.15, which is not the same as the set for Git 2.3.0 or Git 1.7.1.

A verifier, should you wish to construct one, needs an enormous database, which should consist of entries giving:

- the name of the option, such as `pull.rebase` or `push.default`
- the Git versions where the option is introduced and/or modified
- the value(s) available as of that point
- whether some value is deprecated: e.g., since 2.18, you probably should stop using `preserve` in favor of `merges`

and then you can ask: *for Git version x.y, what settings are valid for this configuration item*.  It would also be nice to include the *default* default, as it were, since those change too.

For `push.default` in particular, the setting came into existence with Git 1.6.3, but it defaulted to `matching` until Git 2.0 when it began to default to `simple`.  However, the `simple` setting didn't even *exist* until Git 1.7.11.

The big database of "settings official Git knows about, and their values" does not exist in reified form, as far as I know.  It would have to be constructed from the Git source.  The Git repository for Git is public and easily searched, as I did for the above examples, but making a complete database would be very time consuming.

(Note that users can invent their own person Git configuration values and settings, by writing their own Git commands, e.g., as shell scripts.)